# Limit Grid to a specific area of the axis

Tags: pgfplots

in a graph which looks roughly like this,

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[       
            width=10cm,
            height=4cm,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=10,
            ymin=-1,
            ymax=5,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center
        ]   
        \end{axis}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to remove the gray grid lines which are in the negative y-range to have undisturbed yticklabels. So basically I just want to have the grid in the positive y range. Is there a way to achieve this, without painting every line individually?

Comment to solution below:
The shorten command in this case lengthens the y-axis whithout lengthening the grid, which solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[       
width=10cm, height=4cm,
xmin=0, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=5,
grid=major,
axis lines=center,
y axis line style={shorten <=-0.5cm},
]   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with grid]

Comment: Perfect, that solved it, merci!